# Javascript: Proper syntax with arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, syntax

Accessing an array element with the following line works great;

```
if (dataset[i].properties.property == "value") { ...
```

However when I want to make it a tad more dynamic, I get stuck. How can I use my own variable to access the array element, as shown below?

```
var myVar = 'property';
if (dataset[i].properties.myVar == "value") { ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `dataset[i].properties[myVar] == 'value'`.

Comment: Never thought it was that easy - I'm totally caught up in between proper syntaxes of both PHP and JS :)

Comment: +1 for the only correct solution. People using `eval` for this should burn in hell.

Comment: +1 Might be worth expanding the explanation a bit though, talking about how `x.y` and `x["y"]` are the exact same thing (barring `y` being a reserved word, of course, in which case only the latter form works reliably), fleshing out with a few examples...